# MGSwipeTableCellDelegate : Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is driving me crazy.

I have implemented MGSwipeTableCell which shows three buttons on the left and one button on the right when it is swiped to the right and left respectively.
https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

But, I am not able to trigger the delegate methods when those buttons are pressed after swiping. Here is an excerpt of my code.

detailviewcontroller.h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MGSwipeTableCellDelegate>
```

detailviewcontroller.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DataStruct *showCredit;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Credit_Cell";
    MGSwipeTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        //cell = [[CreditCustomViewTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Credit_Cell"];
        cell = [[MGSwipeTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Credit_Cell"];
    }
    cell.leftButtons = [self createLeftButtons:3];
    cell.leftSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition3D;

    cell.rightButtons = [self createRightButtons:1];
    cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition3D;
    cell.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}

-(NSArray*) swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell*) cell swipeButtonsForDirection:(MGSwipeDirection)direction
             swipeSettings:(MGSwipeSettings*) swipeSettings expansionSettings:(MGSwipeExpansionSettings*) expansionSettings
{
    NSIndexPath *myPath = [creditTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"Pressed Credit last = %d", myPath.row);
    ...
}
```

My Objective : To get the indexpath.row in which the button is pressed after swiping. Can somebody put me into right direction?

Comment: Vizllx, thanks a lot mate. That method was successfully triggered. I will vote your answer is my ultimate solution. But, I have no idea why below method was not getting triggered. Any idea?

-(NSArray*) swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell*) cell swipeButtonsForDirection:(MGSwipeDirection)direction
             swipeSettings:(MGSwipeSettings*) swipeSettings expansionSettings:(MGSwipeExpansionSettings*) expansionSettings:

@Retro, the method suggested by Vizllx got triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tappedButtonAtIndex` delegate method to get the `indexpath` of the that cell in which the button gets clicked.

```
-(BOOL) swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell*) celll tappedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)index direction:(MGSwipeDirection)direction fromExpansion:(BOOL) fromExpansion{

     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableVw indexPathForCell:celll];
     NSInteger rowOfTheCell = [indexPath row];
     NSInteger sectionOfTheCell = [indexPath section];
     NSLog(@"rowofthecell %ld", rowOfTheCell);
     NSLog(@"sectionOfTheCell %ld", sectionOfTheCell);

     return NO; // If you don't want to hide the cell.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is callback method which work without delegate, you can try that

```
[MGSwipeButton buttonWithTitle:@"More" backgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] callback:^BOOL(MGSwipeTableCell *sender) {
      NSLog(@"Convenience callback for swipe buttons!");
}]
```

Comment: Retro, thanks for your help mate. I am using the same callback code to handle the button action. All I wanted was to get the indexpath.row of the that cell in which the button gets pressed, for that I think I had to trigger the delegate method that gives me indexpath. Just tested the method Vizllx suggested, and that worked.